# Angular/Typescript Models - How to organize

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating this small Angular app in order to create a graph with nodes and links that are shown in an SVG element and that I can save in a database and load back.

I have created 3 main class models to represent the objects of my graph:
Graph, Node, Link

In order to build my graph, I can use different type of Nodes, and I use a string property "type" in the Node class to recognize them. It can be "circle", "square", "rectangle"... etc
Thanks to this, I can display the nodes in my Angular NodeComponent depending on its type property.

The different types of Nodes are listed in a config Object in my environment.
The graphic characteristics of each node is also listed in the config (color, size, edge or ray or L ... etc)

Now here is my problem. I have several checks to perform for each node. And the logic of those checks depend on the type of the node. For exemple, if I calculate the area of my node, the formula won't be the same depending on the type.

What I did now is creating a function in a service. It checks the node type before calculating.

```
calculateArea(node: Node) {

switch (node.type) {
      case 'circle': {
        ...
      }
      case 'square': {
       ...
      }
      case 'rectangle': {
        ...
      }
      default: {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

I have several of those functions. Some of them edit properties of my objects, others are just used to display information in the HTML and shouldn't write any data in my objects (that will be saved in the database)

The thing is, when I want to add a new type of node, I need to go and edit many things in my code:
- The config that lists the different types of nodes
- The config with the graphic characteristics of my new node type
- The different functions in each of the services, adding a case with code
and so on...

This doesn't seem to be very optimal.

Is there a way to organize and structure the code so that I can create a new type of Node more easily.

I thought about creating distinct classes Circle, Square, Rectangle... and so on... with static properties (color, ray, edge...) and maybe make them implement an Interface (with several methods: calculateArea...). I also thought about making them extend the Node class.

But then I would have graphic properties (that are currently in my config) repeated in my different objects and in my database, and I would have to implement all the methods although some of them don't need to be implemented (we can use a default method)

What is the best solution to organize my code?
The idea being... if I want to create a new type of node "Star", I would just create a new ts file (with a class) with all the info there, and I would just reference this file somewhere in my code (so my app knows this new type of node exists)

The final goal is also, at some point, to lazyload those different types of Nodes (with the graphic characteristics, chunks of code the functions..) when the user decides to add one to the graph.

Please, let me know if this is unclear. Also, I hope my question is not too trivial.
Thank you

Comment: You really need to read about SOLID principles. These will save you tons of time in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am looking into this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't create separate distinct classes, you can still define `calculateArea` on your Node class so your services don't have to be responsible for calculating those properties on any given Node, and so your services don't need to change whenever your set of supported nodes change.

This doesn't necessarily imply that Node is an abstract base class from which distinct classes Circle, Square, and Rectangle descend. Even if you were to just switch based on `this.type` in your Node, this might be a better for code organization's sake. You then have an option of reading the configuration file inside of Node or a Node factory (a static method or separate class that creates Node instances as needed).

However, thinking about your problem, it makes sense to me that Circle, Square, and Rectangle are going to require *different code*: They don't all calculate their areas the same way. Because of this, I think it would be hard to write a single config file that represents all of the ways your Nodes can vary. Instead I think you should go with your idea of creating separate concrete classes for each of your Node types, because you will need to change the code in order to support new node types anyway. For similar problems that don't require code to vary—a driving game where you support configuration-based makes, models, and colors of cars, for instance—you can definitely put self-contained logic in your model objects without creating polymorphic subclasses.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff. I will try and look into this path then. I need to better understand how Interface and Inheritance works in Typescript...

Comment: Also, since I got ur attention, is there a way to lazy load those new classes in Angular, whenever the user "imports" a new shape in his graph? (suposing he has the list of all available shapes to select from) I know how to lazy load entire modules, but not a single class. Is it possible in Angular?

Comment: @march That's better asked as a top-level question.